# how MIME types are connected to content providers

Tags: java, android

the android documentation states that a MIME type must be returned for every URI, if I understand it correctly. I do not understand the connection between MIME type and Content Providers. What is it used for ?

Comment: I'd start from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351669/why-use-contentprovider-gettype-to-get-mime-type

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the dataType in an IntentFilter and use that to resolve the Intent.  The data type is a mime type and android uses the installed content providers to validate that the mime type can be supported.

One place this is used is for the ContactsContract provider, since third party providers can define custom datatypes that can be added to a contact along with the activities that can manage those datatypes.